# SQLite select query with where cluase

Tags: android, select, sqlite, where-clause

I have the following function for `SQLite select` statement

```
public Boolean itemFound(String cartId,Long ItemId){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.d("search",cartId+"--"+ItemId);

        try {
            String where = COL_ITEM_CART_ID+"='"+cartId+"' and "+COL_ITEM_ID+" ="+ ItemId+"";
            Log.d("where===============", where);
            String columns[] = new String[] { COL_ITEM_ID,COL_ITEM_NAME, COL_ITEM_PRICE, COL_ITEM_ADDDATE,COL_ITEM_QUANTITY,COL_ITEM_CART_ID }; // > null means * (all)
            Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
                                columns ,
                                COL_ITEM_CART_ID+"='?' and "+ COL_ITEM_ID + "=?"  ,
                                new String[]{cartId,String.valueOf(ItemId)}, 
                                null, 
                                null, 
                                COL_ITEM_ADDDATE+" desc");


            int numRows = c.getCount();

            c.close();
            db.close();
            if(numRows>0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            db.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

where the parameters are :

- `Long` type itemId= 9882889921
- `String` type cartId = ca1745ef-24eb-4da8-a1ea-9650d78ba5c0

Despite there is recode with these data. the returned rows is 0 , why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrapped a `?` in single quotes, change this:

```
COL_ITEM_CART_ID+"='?' and "+ COL_ITEM_ID + "=?"
```

The line above is trying to literally match `COL_ITEM_CART_ID` to a question mark, change it like this:

```
COL_ITEM_CART_ID + "=? and "+ COL_ITEM_ID + "=?"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `query` method will sanitize your data input for you, so when you wrap the `?`s with apostrophes, the apostrophes become part of the input string itself. This is causing your query to return 0 rows.

To fix the problem, remove change all instances of `'?'` to `?`.